# AngularJS $httpBackend 'expect' does not work correctly

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

all!

Using AngularJS, Rails, Jasmine

when I use `expect` from **$httpBackend** service in test,
according to [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) `expect(method, url, [data], [headers]);`

in my test:

```
describe 'when something', ->
  it 'response success', ->
    @http.expect('GET', 'acts/1', {month: '09/2015'}).respond(200)
    @scope.createAct()
    @http.flush()
```

, but, when I run tests, raise exeption:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET acts/1?id=1&month=09%2F2015
Expected GET acts/1
```

I've tried insert data like hash, string, json, result was same...

And it works ONLY if I use url with data:

```
@http.expect('GET', 'acts/1?id=1&month=09%2F2015').respond(200)
```

**So it dosen't work correctly**

maybe someone can say, how I can insert data to `expect` method???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `data` argument in `expect` should only be used if you send a payload in addition to the URL, e.g. when you call `POST` or `PATCH`.

With GET requests, you should include your encoded parameters in the URL, just as you wrote:

```
@http.expect('GET', 'acts/1?id=1&month=09%2F2015').respond(200)
```

Comment: no you'r wrong. According to official documentation i can add data to expect with GET method. So it have to works! but it doesn't

Comment: I'm looking at [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#expect) and they say: data (optional): HTTP request body (...) -- GETs have no request body.